# How to get "It's Truly Random!" achievement on LEGO Universe

Tags: lego-universe

When playing LEGO Universe, there is an achievement called "It''s Truly Random!", which one must roll a six on "the LEGO die" one hundred times (in a row?) to get.

This definition is very vague and leaves me with little to no idea of how to actually get this achievement.

Must I possibly make a video of doing this in real life with my LEGO die? Or is there a LEGO die in LEGO Universe?

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news :( http://imgur.com/Qv537

Comment: @Aardvark Yeah, I know ... boo hoo ... :(

Comment: you roll that dice buddy, you roll it like its your last!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a LEGO Die in LEGO Universe.

From [GeekDad](http://www.wired.com/geekdad/2011/05/10-lego-universe-items-you-should-have/)

> There is a skeleton cage just past Merciless Ned before Brig Rock in Gnarled Fortress. Avoid the Stromling Ape that likes to guard this area, and spin the cage 25 times to win the LEGO Die item.

To get the achievement, you have to roll a total of 100 sixes, but they don't have to be all in a row.